# Sintaxis LIKE 'DATO%' no funciona en MySql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla donde los registros tienen una columna fechaused, cuando son llamados se registra la fecha exacta cuando fueron usados, con un query quiero cambiar la columna estado a `estado = '1'` que significa usado, la fecha la guardo de la siguiente manera: `2020-09-05 02:05:38 PM`, y el query es el siguiente:

`` UPDATE `usuarios` SET `estado`='1' WHERE `fechaused` LIKE '2020-09-05 02%' ``

pero este query me devuelve 0 columnas afectadas, siendo que si existen registros con esa fecha.

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es la columna `fechaused` en la tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de darle el formato antes de compararlo con `2020-09-05 02%`

Trata de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE `usuarios` SET `estado`='1' WHERE DATE(fechaused) LIKE '2020-09-05 02%'
```

Comment: Si usas date entonces el 02 no será considerado